# Excel matching second column in data range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, match, matching

I have a list of product names (many duplicates) in column M, and also a list of product names (no duplicates) in column O with their corresponding costs in column P.

I would like to use the matching function to match the product name in column M with the same product name in column O with that product's cost and put that cost in column N.

This is the function I am using:

```
=INDEX(data,(MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(M2,O2:O501),0),2)
```

My data is in a range from `O2:P501`. I don't understand why it isn't working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you would be better of with a `VLOOKUP` for this situation, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to use Index/Match, this would to the job:

```
=INDEX($P$2:$P$501,MATCH(M2,$O$2:$O$501,0))
```